# Expansion panels in Google Material design android

Tags: android, material-design

I am just looking for an example for expansion panels in android (Material design).

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/expansion-panels.html

I know we have expandable listview.  But, I need to show some additional layout view on expanding each panel similar to Accordian view.  How can we achieve this in android?

Answer (score 6):

Try the expandable layout  [here](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout) . It can have the same behaviour as an Accordian

Include it to your gradle with `compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.5.1@aar'`
**Example**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/accordian_header"
    android:clickable="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/accordian_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Title" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/down_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />
</RelativeLayout>
<com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableLinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="14dp"
        android:paddingRight="14dp"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        app:ael_expanded="false"
        app:ael_duration="500"
        app:ael_orientation="vertical">
<!--add your content here -->
  </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableLinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your **java code**

```
ExpandableLinearLayout content=(ExpandableLinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);
RelativeLayout header=(RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.accordian_header);

//to toggle content
header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                content.toggle();
            }
        });
```

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: why this expandableList don't expand when first click? I use three different library but all make same problem.